# Can't Connect to Postgres on Docker Container via pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

I have pulled postgres image with docker pull postgres.
I have also tried to run image from https://docs.docker.com/examples/postgresql_service/

I run them with -p 5432:5432 option, but could not connect with pgAdmin.
It gave me timeout when I tried to connect via localhost:5432.
Examples I found on the internet say just use -p. I did, and it does not work. 
Also security settings at least from example above are very permissive.
Any suggestions?

Comment: forgot to mention that I have been working under OS X

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on how you ran Docker, this is not likely to work. The Docker Daemon runs in a virtual machine on OS X, which means you actually need to connect to that IP address (rather than localhost). To find that IP address, type the following:

`docker-machine ip default`

The IP you get back will tell you the IP to connect to.

Comment: thank you, your solution works for me! before I was trying to get it through docker inspect 85e44387c718 with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Examples I followed work for Linux, but don't work for OS X. 
When you connect to postgres from OS X, you don't use 'localhost:5432', but IP:5432. The right IP you can find from[image: Container in Kinematic]